# Problemas ao gerar uma View em PDF usando Rotativa

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, pdf

Estou tentando aprender como fazer uma View ser convertida no formato PDF para poder ser impressa ou baixada por um usuário.

Li alguns posts e resolvi seguir a indicação de uma biblioteca chamada [Rotativa](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/335595/rotativa-how-to-print-pdf-in-asp-net-mvc) que parecia bem simples de usar.

Ela realmente gerou um PDF, mas o PDF gerado veio com a minha página de Login da aplicação, ao invés da View que foi passada para a Action.

Creio que tenha algo a ver com direitos de acesso. Tentei colocar um [AllowAnonymous] sobre a Action mas isso não mudou o resultado.

O código do controller é simples e foi feito seguindo as orientações da página do Rotativa:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult CriarRelatorioEmPDF(FiltroDeTarefaHorasViewModel model)
    {
        model = CarregarModelo(model);

        return new ActionAsPdf("RelatorioEmPDF", model ) { FileName = "RelatorioDeHoras.pdf" };            
    }

    public ActionResult RelatorioEmPDF(FiltroDeTarefaHorasViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo e como resolver?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Como você está chamando a `Action`?

Comment: Chamei por um ActionLink:@Html.ActionLink("Gerar PDF", "CriarRelatorioEmPDF", Model, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-print" }) e verifiquei, está recebendo o model com todos os seus valores.